# Python - SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE, is this a cipher or a cert issue?

Tags: python, ssl

I am trying to execute a https url via the python requests API, however I get an error:

```
  File "<console>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 72, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 58, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 513, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 623, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:579)
```

I thought this might be a untrusted warning so I used

```
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
```

but this hasn't worked, further searching suggests it might be something to do with ciphers?

my code as per the below:

```
import requests
username="ncm"
password="*****"
headers={'content-type':'application/json'}
response = requests.get('https://10.55.244.2/level/15/exec/-/traceroute/10.50.0.1/source/vlan/5/CR',
                        verify=False,
                        auth=(username, password),
                        headers=headers,
                        timeout=4)
```

the certificate presented
[image: certificate info]

Comment: A handshake failure usually relates to an SSL misconfiguration or incompatibility.

Comment: would this be ciphers then? do I need to specify a cipher set? how do I fix this? Thanks

Comment: @KlausD. any ideas?

Comment: Relevant: [sslv3 alert handshake failure when using SSL client auth ](https://github.com/coreos/etcd/issues/209)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some searching I found using urlib2 works, the below code will work without error

```
import urllib2, base64
request = urllib2.Request('https://yoururl')
base64string = base64.b64encode('%s:%s' % (username, password))
request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)   
result = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```